# Acumatica PXDefault Drop List

Tags: drop-down-menu, acumatica, default-value

I'm trying to change the default value to `Debit Memo` when adding a new row in the Payments and Applications screen of the Accounts Receivable module.  I've tried setting `PXDefault(ARDocType.DebitMemo)`, but it doesn't appear to be working.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Add your code to the question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payments and applications page uses some interesting logic to determine the default value used, they define it in a call during the rowselected event for the header document.

```
protected virtual void ARPayment_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
.....
SetDocTypeList(e.Row);
.....
}


    public static void SetDocTypeList(PXCache cache, string docType)
    {
        string defValue = ARDocType.Invoice;
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        List<string> labels = new List<string>();

        if (docType == ARDocType.Refund)
        {
            defValue = ARDocType.CreditMemo;
            values.AddRange(new string[] { ARDocType.CreditMemo, ARDocType.Payment, ARDocType.Prepayment });
            labels.AddRange(new string[] { Messages.CreditMemo, Messages.Payment, Messages.Prepayment });
        }
        else if (docType == ARDocType.Payment || docType == ARDocType.VoidPayment)
        {
            values.AddRange(new string[] { ARDocType.Invoice, ARDocType.DebitMemo, ARDocType.CreditMemo, ARDocType.FinCharge });
            labels.AddRange(new string[] { Messages.Invoice, Messages.DebitMemo, Messages.CreditMemo, Messages.FinCharge });
        }
        else
        {
            values.AddRange(new string[] { ARDocType.Invoice, ARDocType.DebitMemo, ARDocType.FinCharge });
            labels.AddRange(new string[] { Messages.Invoice, Messages.DebitMemo, Messages.FinCharge });
        }

        if (!PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.overdueFinCharges>() && values.Contains(ARDocType.FinCharge) && labels.Contains(Messages.FinCharge))
        {
            values.Remove(ARDocType.FinCharge);
            labels.Remove(Messages.FinCharge);
        }

        PXDefaultAttribute.SetDefault<ARAdjust.adjdDocType>(cache, defValue);
        PXStringListAttribute.SetList<ARAdjust.adjdDocType>(cache, null, values.ToArray(), labels.ToArray());
    }

    private void SetDocTypeList(object Row)
    {
        ARPayment row = Row as ARPayment;
        if (row != null)
        {
            SetDocTypeList(Adjustments.Cache, row.DocType);
        }
    }
```

To obtain the default you require you may implement the following code :

```
public class ARPaymentEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<ARPaymentEntry>
{
    protected virtual void ARPayment_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
            PXDefaultAttribute.SetDefault<ARAdjust.adjdDocType>(Base.Adjustments.Cache, ARDocType.DebitMemo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for your help.